# Get content Type of WCF response

Tags: c#, wcf, http, mime

I have a WCF client that download content from the server.

the service contract is;

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(
                UriTemplate = "/my/service/url/{method}/{filename}?tradeId={tradeId}&docType={docType}&language={language}&version={version}",
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        Stream GetDocument(string method, string filename, string tradeId, string docType, string version, string language);
```

The return type is a Stream. What I do is simply just write that stream to a file and it works.

Now, I want to make modification on this. I want to know the MIME type of the downloaded document. I know it is set properly on the server. I simply need to retrieve it.

I have little experience with WCF and don't know how to do that. Can someone let me know?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must get access to `OperationContext` or `WebOperationContext`. To achieve that on a client use `OperationContextScope`:

```
using (var scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)proxy))
{
    Stream document = proxy.GetDocument(...);
    string contentType = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingResponse.ContentType;
}
```